# Python - download entire directory from Google Cloud Storage with progress bar

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, cmd, progress-bar

I am downloading a entire directory from Google Cloud Storage using below python code

```
from google.cloud import storage
from pathlib import Path

def download_blob():
"""Downloads a blob from the bucket."""
# The ID of your GCS bucket
bucket_name = "Bucket name"

# The ID of your GCS object
blob_name = input("Enter the folder name in "+bucket_name+" : ")

storage_client = storage.Client()

bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
blobs = bucket.list_blobs(prefix=blob_name)  # Get list of files
print('Downloading file')
for blob in blobs:
    if blob.name.endswith("/"):
       continue
    file_split = blob.name.split("/")
    directory = "/".join(file_split[0:-1])
    Path(directory).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    blob.download_to_filename(blob.name) 
print('Download completed')

download_blob()
```

How to show progress bar after printing the line "Downloading File"

Comment: When i tried to make a progress bar using tqdm. First i imported tqdm with the code, "from tqdm.std import tqdm" then wrapped tqdm around my iterator blobs , code sample looks like "for blob in tqdm(blobs):" . the output i got is                                         "Downloading
5it [00:11,  2.32s/it]
Download Completed" there is no progress bar just a count from oit to 5it occurs.

Comment: When i used tqdm's trange to wrap the iterator it returns the error "TypeError: 'HTTPIterator' object cannot be interpreted as an integer". Do anyone know how to iterate over HTTPIterator

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that you have a Python library that is capable of showing a progress bar on the console/terminal where you plan to run this program.

What you can do at a coarse level is the following:

- You have a list of blobs that are present in the specific Google Cloud Bucket + prefix.
- For each of the blob, you have a property named `size`. This can tell you the number of bytes that are there for each of the blobs.
- You can sum up first the total number of bytes that make up all the blobs and then start the `download_to_filename` loop, where you go through downloading each blob and then everytime that download is complete, you update the % complete in the progress bar.

Alternatively, if you really want fine grained percentage, then you probably need to use the `start` and `end` parameters of the `download_to_filename` method, where you can get specific number of bytes only. Refer to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/storage/latest/google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob#google_cloud_storage_blob_Blob_download_to_filename).

Comment: I used tqdm python library for getting the progress bar. But it is not showing progress bar, it just shows some counts per iteration. To know more you can read my comments in question section

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with this, because the main issue is that you will only know the actual length of your iterator after you iterate over it. That's the reason why your tqdm is unable to show the progress bar.

Since for my use case showing the progress bar is a requirement while fetching the blobs form Google, I made sure to iterate over it once by wrapping it to a `list()` first and then Iterate over the list instead of the actual blobs iterator. For your code it would look like this:

```
from google.cloud import storage
from pathlib import Path
from tqdm import tqdm

def download_blob():
"""Downloads a blob from the bucket."""
# The ID of your GCS bucket
bucket_name = "Bucket name"

# The ID of your GCS object
blob_name = input("Enter the folder name in "+bucket_name+" : ")

storage_client = storage.Client()

bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
blobs = bucket.list_blobs(prefix=blob_name)  # Get list of files
print('Downloading file')
blob_list = list(blobs)
for blob in tqdm(blob_list):
    if blob.name.endswith("/"):
       continue
    file_split = blob.name.split("/")
    directory = "/".join(file_split[0:-1])
    Path(directory).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    blob.download_to_filename(blob.name) 
print('Download completed')

download_blob()
```

Aa far as I know, this is the only way I got it to work to actually see the progress bar. In my scenario I never had more than 100 blobs in my iterator and my script doesn't have a time limit, so I had no issue iterating twice over my blobs.